# How to find current zoom level in a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dictionary

How do I find the current zoom level when loading or clicking a Google map?

Comment: um, [`Map.getZoom()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If you have a map object like this:

```
var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), _mapOptions);
```

use

```
mapObject.getZoom();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mapObject.getZoom();`?

Comment: fixed GetZoom() --> getZoom()

Comment: its not working for me can someone pls tell me how to do that ?

Comment: If you are using google maps api2, then you have to do it like this: `map.getCameraPosition().zoom`

Comment: How to do this in react-native-maps ?

Answer (score 20):

Use this code:

```
float zoomlevel = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to get zoom on change

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log(zoom);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it using:

```
console.log(this.map.zoom);
```

I'm using [agm-angular-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/)

**html:**

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
```

**TS:**

```
onMapReady(map) {
 this.map = map;
}
```