# How to get current zoom level in openstreetmap?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I am creating a Heat Map with Open Street Map (OSM). When I zoom in I am not sure what zoom level I am at and at which coordinate position. I wanted to get those numbers for future reference if I want to get there directly.

Is there a Open Street Map API or hack that can return the zoom level of the map?

How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find current zoom level in a Google Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385703/how-to-find-current-zoom-level-in-a-google-map) (both questions are about Google Maps API v3, the tile service provider doesn't really matter here).

Comment: Unless the person asking the question is using leaflet or open layers. Need more details to provide an answer.

Comment: @asax If this question is still relevant, what are you using to display OpenStreetMap data? Leaflet, OpenLayers, QGIS, anything else?

Answer (score 2):

There is getZoom() method in OpenStreetMap API which can be used to get current zoom level. For more information see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers