# Map - need to list the items that are only in the zoomed view

Tags: android, html

I am using an indoormap where I am showing the list of poi present in it, my requirement is to show the list of poi in the zoom position only.

can anyone suggest me for knowing the zoomed position bounds in html.

Comment: if you are using google maps api -->   http://stackoverflow.com/a/6385750/6414107 . might help

Comment: Since maps aren't part of Android natively, we'd need to know what mapping library you were using.

Comment: I am using SVG maps, I am wrting the code in HTML and calling that file in android.