# How to find the current zoom level in percentage after scrolling or increasing Zoom level of a Google map?

Tags: javascript

When I opening the website google map is opened. Then I scroll the googles map to increase zoom to find a more accurate place. Then I again go back to the previous page, but the googles map goes to the state same as it is open the first time. What will I do?

As `map.setZoom(12);` show the zoom level which is set in the javascript code, not the current zoom level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find current zoom level in a Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385703/how-to-find-current-zoom-level-in-a-google-map)

Comment: No, That question is regarding current zoom which is set in code. I am asking how to find zoom level of googles map when we zoom dynamically while running the application.

Comment: You will find a similar question being answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385703/how-to-find-current-zoom-level-in-a-google-map

Comment: @VasileFlorinVilsan That is the exact same question I linked to. Also, did you even try the answers in the linked question? I'm pretty sure and event listener will work regardless if the zoom level is changed with your own code or by user input.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but It doesn't work for me. It only gives me the static zoom value.